# How many times can I attempt to open the Whisper-locked box from Fallen London?

Tags: sunless-sea

There is a storylet in Fallen London that will provide a [whisper-locked box](http://sunlesssea.gamepedia.com/Whisper-Locked_Puzzle-Box) for "my next Captain".  Is this a once-only bonus, or would it unlock a Starting Ambition that I could pick any number of times?

(I thought it would only work once, so I've been afraid to connect my account until I thought I had a reasonable chance of accomplishing a Quest -- but it sounds like [maybe I was wrong](http://community.failbettergames.com/topic10131-how-important-is-the-whisperlocked-box.aspx)?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every captain, beginning with the **next one after you connect the account**, receives a chest, regardless of what previous captains have done with it, including finishing the related quest or throwing it in the waves.

The chest shows up as an item that does not take up space in your hold, and possession of it allows you to take it to the Alarming Scholar in London to begin the quest to open it, though at many points during the quest you can also sell it, and you can also attempt to force it open or sacrifice it to Salt at any time from your hold. The quest is not an Ambition, nor does it replace one.

The "next Captain" line is a very poorly worded method of indicating that you won't receive it until you die, if you have a game already in progress.

Answer (score -1):

You get it once. It gives you a handful of goodies. Nothing gamebreaking, but helps push through the starting hump.

According to user Ranneko on reddit, it's one per captain.

Comment: Once _per captain_, or once _ever_ (for only one captain)?

Comment: I'll pick through the files tonight and update the wiki accordingly, but fairly certain it's once ever.

Comment: I would appreciate that.  I'm mainly afraid of connecting my account, getting the Box story with a low-survivability captain and dying on my one-and-only chance to complete its story.

Comment: Sorry. Just realised that I didn't actually answer your question. First up: added all the interactions here: http://sunlesssea.gamepedia.com/Whisper-Locked_Puzzle-Box. Secondly, it's once per account. So one box, once.

Comment: You're sure the WLPB quality that gets reset is the Metaquality, and not just a regular quality that gets set because the Metaquality is present (like with the S&C Long-box)?  Because [I'm getting conflicting answers now](http://www.reddit.com/r/sunlesssea/comments/2zwhst/how_many_times_can_i_attempt_to_open_the/cpmz0qc).

Comment: The "persistent" value in the game file is set to false, so it should disappear with your captain. That being said, I haven't got it in-game (I didn't realise the fallen london storylet was important at the time), so there might be something I'm missing - for example, it might update the file so persistent is set to true when you get the update from the server. If Ranneko has actually had it more than once, then I'd go with his answer. Sorry for the confusion around this. I'll update my answer if you get a confirmation from him.

Comment: Ranneko confirmed that every captain gets one box.